# SeqIO.parse throwing error in genbank files

Tags: biopython, seq, genbank

I'm working with some genbank seq files and have the following code:

```
for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("datafile_location, "genbank"):
```

And while it can run through most of the seqs in the seq file (which contains multiple seqs) I get the following error. Any thoughts about how to fix this?

Maybe delete the offending seq? It gets to record `92126` of `93145` and then throws the error.

I have tried re-downloading the seq file, but that doesn't fix the problem.

> File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\Bio\GenBank\Scanner.py", line 516,
>   in parse_records record = self.parse(handle, do_features) File
>   "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\Bio\GenBank\Scanner.py", line 499, in
>   parse if self.feed(handle, consumer, do_features): File
>   "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\Bio\GenBank\Scanner.py", line 466, in
>   feed self._feed_header_lines(consumer, self.parse_header()) File
>   "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\Bio\GenBank\Scanner.py", line 1801, in
>   feed_header_lines previous_value_line = structured_comment_dict[ KeyError: 'Assembly-Data'

Answer (score 1):

Seems similar like [BioPython issue #2844](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/2844).

A [pull request was recently merged](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/2851) to address this.